# librdkafka producer to take a message from a function and produce it on topic

Tags: c, apache-kafka, librdkafka

Being relatively new to Kafka, I'm having trouble implementing a Kafka Producer where it receives an input `message` from a function and further produce it on the topic defined. But the difficulty is that it takes a lot of time to post it on the topic. And if I try to change it's configuration, it either skips a few messages or the speed with which the messages are being produced on the topic is slowed. I will post my producer code below, and would be extremely grateful if somebody could help me through it as I have no idea where I am wrong.

**CODE:-**

```
int rdkafka_produce (json_object *message) {
    rd_kafka_t *rk;         /* Producer instance handle */
    rd_kafka_topic_t *rkt;  /* Topic object */
    rd_kafka_conf_t *conf;  /* Temporary configuration object */
    char errstr[512];       /* librdkafka API error reporting buffer */
    char buf[2048];          /* Message value temporary buffer */
    const char *brokers;    /* Argument: broker list */
    const char *topic;      /* Argument: topic to produce to */
    int sendcnt=0;
    int partition = RD_KAFKA_PARTITION_UA;
    rd_kafka_topic_conf_t *topic_conf;
    rd_kafka_resp_err_t err;
    rd_kafka_headers_t *hdrs = NULL;

    /*
     * Argument validation
     */

    brokers = "localhost:9092";
    topic   = "tt_stream";


    /*
     * Create Kafka client configuration place-holder
     */
    conf = rd_kafka_conf_new();

    /* Set bootstrap broker(s) as a comma-separated list of
     * host or host:port (default port 9092).
     * librdkafka will use the bootstrap brokers to acquire the full
     * set of brokers from the cluster. */
    if (rd_kafka_conf_set(conf, "bootstrap.servers", brokers,
                          errstr, sizeof(errstr)) != RD_KAFKA_CONF_OK) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", errstr);
            return 1;
    }

    /* Set the delivery report callback.
     * This callback will be called once per message to inform
     * the application if delivery succeeded or failed.
     * See dr_msg_cb() above. */
    rd_kafka_conf_set_dr_msg_cb(conf, dr_msg_cb);
                    if (!(rk = rd_kafka_new(RD_KAFKA_PRODUCER, conf,
                                    errstr, sizeof(errstr)))) {
                    fprintf(stderr,
                            "%% Failed to create new producer: %s\n",
                            errstr);
                    exit(1);
            }

            /* Add brokers */
            if (rd_kafka_brokers_add(rk, brokers) == 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "%% No valid brokers specified\n");
    /* Set the delivery report callback.
     * This callback will be called once per message to inform
     * the application if delivery succeeded or failed.
     * See dr_msg_cb() above. */
    rd_kafka_conf_set_dr_msg_cb(conf, dr_msg_cb);
                    if (!(rk = rd_kafka_new(RD_KAFKA_PRODUCER, conf,
                                    errstr, sizeof(errstr)))) {
                    fprintf(stderr,
                            "%% Failed to create new producer: %s\n",
                            errstr);
                    exit(1);
            }

            /* Add brokers */
            if (rd_kafka_brokers_add(rk, brokers) == 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "%% No valid brokers specified\n");
                    exit(1);
            }

            /* Create topic */
            rkt = rd_kafka_topic_new(rk, topic, topic_conf);
            topic_conf = NULL; /* Now owned by topic */


    //while (run && strcpy(buf, json_object_to_json_string(message))) {

    strcpy(buf, json_object_to_json_string(message));
                    size_t len = strlen(buf);
                    if (buf[len-1] == '\n')
                            buf[--len] = '\0';

                    err = RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR_NO_ERROR;

                    /* Send/Produce message. */
                    if (hdrs) {
                            rd_kafka_headers_t *hdrs_copy;

                            hdrs_copy = rd_kafka_headers_copy(hdrs);

                            err = rd_kafka_producev(
                                    rk,
                                    RD_KAFKA_V_RKT(rkt),
                                    RD_KAFKA_V_PARTITION(partition),
                                    RD_KAFKA_V_MSGFLAGS(RD_KAFKA_MSG_F_COPY),
                                    RD_KAFKA_V_VALUE(buf, len),
                                    RD_KAFKA_V_HEADERS(hdrs_copy),
                                    RD_KAFKA_V_END);

                            if (err)
                                    rd_kafka_headers_destroy(hdrs_copy);

                    } else {
                            if (rd_kafka_produce(
                                        rkt, partition,
                                        RD_KAFKA_MSG_F_COPY,
                                        /* Payload and length */
                                        buf, len,
                                        /* Optional key and its length */
                                        NULL, 0,
                                        /* Message opaque, provided in
                                         * delivery report callback as
                                         * msg_opaque. */
                                        NULL) == -1) {
                                    err = rd_kafka_last_error();
                            }
                    }

                    if (err) {
                            fprintf(stderr,
                                    "%% Failed to produce to topic %s "
                                    "partition %i: %s\n",
                                    rd_kafka_topic_name(rkt), partition,
                                    rd_kafka_err2str(err));

                            /* Poll to handle delivery reports */
                            rd_kafka_poll(rk, 0);
                    }

                    sendcnt++;
                    /* Poll to handle delivery reports */
                    rd_kafka_poll(rk, 0);
            //}

            /* Poll to handle delivery reports */
            rd_kafka_poll(rk, 0);

            /* Wait for messages to be delivered */
            while (run && rd_kafka_outq_len(rk) > 0)
                    rd_kafka_poll(rk, 100);         //This is where most of the time is being spent.

            /* Destroy topic */
            rd_kafka_topic_destroy(rkt);

            /* Destroy the handle */
            rd_kafka_destroy(rk);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new producer client instance for each message you produce;
this is very costly since it needs to spin up threads, connect to the bootstrap brokers, authenticate, perform metadata lookups, connect to proper brokers, etc, before being able to produce the single message.

Instead have a single long-lived producer instance that you reuse for each message, this will cut down your latency to a handful of milliseconds (depending on broker connectivity and load).